# How to get the height of div when height is set in CSS file?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

The div is been generated at run time in js file. The height of the div is defined in class. Now I want to get the height of this div.

I have already tried :-

```
$('.maxHeight').height();
     $('.maxHeight').inner-height();
     $('.maxHeight').outer-height();
     $('.maxHeight').offset-height();
     $('.maxHeight').client-height();
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$('.maxHeight').css('height')`? and `.height()` should have worked

Comment: Yes, It is returning 0px, although the height is more than 425px.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code?

Comment: How many element with `maxHeight` you have?

Comment: Including the css.

Comment: Try `$('.maxHeight').height();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.maxHeight:eq(0)').css("height");
```

That should work. Make sure it is selecting your actual div, and not a different one that has the same class. Use the [0] if you have multiple instances

Comment: It depends on whether you have multiples or not.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong there. To specify one specific element you need to use  `:eq( 2 )-selector` like this: `$('.maxHeight:eq(0)').css("height");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the DOM-three to finish before you can run you javascript.

Try to put you code in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($('.maxHeight').css("height"));
})
```